# github squash and merge how to keep it at par with develop

Tags: github

I have a `feature` branch which is only allowing `squash and merge` option on github.
At the same time `develop` branch is also being worked upon so `feature` branch becomes:

`x` commits ahead and `y` commits behind develop

Now how do i make the `feature` branch at par with develop

how to make `feature` branch:
`x` commits ahead of develop and no commits behind develop?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is merge develop into your feature branch;

```
git fetch
git checkout <your feature branch name>
git merge develop
```